# Xcode Ignored Symbols

Tags: ios, xcode

When building my project, I get the following warning lines:

```
Warning: Ignored symbols were detected in this build. In some cases ignored symbols could cause incorrect finalization. This may be caused by different static libraries containing the same symbol. 
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0xa9d4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0xa9d8 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0xc9ec -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0xc9f0 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '_int_update' defined at address 0x1e0e18 -- it was already defined at 0x1baef4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e26fc -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e2704 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e270c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e2724 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e272c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e2734 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e274c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e2754 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e275c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e2774 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e277c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e2784 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e279c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e27a4 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e27ac -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e27c4 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e27cc -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e27d4 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e27ec -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e27f4 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e27fc -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e2814 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e281c -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e2824 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0x1e2b78 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26d4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0x1e2b80 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26dc
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0x1e2b88 -- it was already defined at 0x1e26e4
Ignored symbol '_table_cmp_BSEARCH_CMP_FN' defined at address 0x2317f4 -- it was already defined at 0x19e718
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x235cb4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x235cc4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2368d4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2368e4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23af78 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23af9c -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23c3b0 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23c3c0 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23f83c -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x23f84c -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2431cc -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2431dc -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x243fa0 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x243fd0 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2456d4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2456e4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x248fb4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x248fc4 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x24db24 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x24db34 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x250348 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x250358 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2512c8 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x2512ec -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_91' defined at address 0x2516e8 -- it was already defined at 0x23f934
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_92' defined at address 0x251718 -- it was already defined at 0x23f958
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x253d58 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x253d68 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x253f00 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x253f10 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_152' defined at address 0x254ba8 -- it was already defined at 0x235e58
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_153' defined at address 0x254bb8 -- it was already defined at 0x235e88
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_174' defined at address 0x254f00 -- it was already defined at 0x2491c8
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_175' defined at address 0x254f10 -- it was already defined at 0x2491ec
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_193' defined at address 0x2550fc -- it was already defined at 0x24e81c
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_194' defined at address 0x255120 -- it was already defined at 0x24e82c
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_254' defined at address 0x255a78 -- it was already defined at 0x24eec8
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_255' defined at address 0x255a9c -- it was already defined at 0x24eed8
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_321' defined at address 0x255f4c -- it was already defined at 0x24f93c
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_322' defined at address 0x255fa0 -- it was already defined at 0x24f94c
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_369' defined at address 0x2567d8 -- it was already defined at 0x242a94
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_370' defined at address 0x2567e8 -- it was already defined at 0x242aa4
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x257828 -- it was already defined at 0x4d64
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_' defined at address 0x257838 -- it was already defined at 0x4d68
Ignored symbol '___copy_helper_block_106' defined at address 0x258280 -- it was already defined at 0x251960
Ignored symbol '___destroy_helper_block_107' defined at address 0x2582b0 -- it was already defined at 0x251970
Ignored symbol '_BitStreamGetBits' defined at address 0x25aae8 -- it was already defined at 0x25a320
Ignored symbol '_BitStreamGetBits' defined at address 0x25b4b0 -- it was already defined at 0x25a320
Ignored symbol '_BitStreamGetBits' defined at address 0x25c204 -- it was already defined at 0x25a320
Ignored symbol '_BitStreamGetBits' defined at address 0x267428 -- it was already defined at 0x25a320
Ignored symbol '_BitStreamGetBits' defined at address 0x268ec8 -- it was already defined at 0x25a320
```

I have tried to track the problem down by removing certain libraries but nothing works so far. Are there other options to track this warning down?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had a very similar issue myself...   had to do a clean, then rebuild of the solution...   problem went away.  not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to clean then re-build but the error still comes up.

Comment: One last thing to check, is that there are no duplicate files...  i know it sounds stupid simple, but sometimes the solution manager / project does repeat files from time to time.

Comment: Yeah I looked in Link Binary with Libraries and there were no duplicates.

Comment: i'm afraid i've exhausted my bag of tricks....   one last thing to try would be to create a new project and start moving stuff over....  very last resort, but sometimes, it might just work.  best of luck

Comment: It would be faster to only add libraries one by one to the new empty project rather than move everything. If the new project with all libraries builds fine you might want to start looking at your own code (it is also possible that you have the same library added as a binary and source code).

Comment: did you find what was the cause?